# Python read array from file

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

Pretty new to Python so I'm struggling picking this part up.
I want to put arrays into a text file and have them called with in my .py

Here is what I had:

```
import json
myfile = open("lists.txt")
myVars = json.load(myfile)
myVars['alist']
```

and in the lists.txt file:

```
{
    "alist" : [
        ["1", "2", "3"]
    ],
    "b" : [
        ["test"]
    ]
}
```

I called it in my .py with:

```
if message.body == "!r alist":
    room.message("I recommend: " + choice(alist))
    print("did it work?")
```

(choice is just to get a random one, etc.)

Comment: So, did it work? What's the question?

Comment: The cmd just closes without any indication why. When I comment out everything with loading the array it works so the problem is with this

Comment: How do you run your file?

Comment: clicking on my .py (runbot.py) - this is a chatbot that uses ch.py,

Comment: If you want the view the error message (or output), run your .py from the command line or inside your IDE (like IDLE)

Comment: It's coming up as NameError: global name 'myVars' is not defined  so I changed + choice(alist)) to + choice(myVers)) and I still get that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is not adding up with the code snippets.  Your json loading is fine.  You can pass a file pointer to json.load

The problem looks to be here:

```
if message.body == "!r alist":
  room.message("I recommend: " + choice(alist))
  print("did it work?")
```

Is choice a method/function?  Where is it defined?  Where is alist declared in this code snippet.  After loading the json file you need to access alist using:

```
myAList = myVars['alist']
choice(myAList[0])
```

Assuming that choice is a valid method that can access myAList.  I suspect you are not connecting the pieces of code together properly.

Comment: I put open list.txt on def onConnect(self, room): this is where I also parse a url.
Choice is from random import choice

Answer (score -1):

You're only referencing a file pointer... You're not actually loading in the data.

```
myfile = open('lists.txt').read()
```

That should give you your string which you can then load into an object using json

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read' is the error, has that got to do something with the json.load right under it?

Comment: Ah apologies, try using this with json.loads(myfile), I read your json function call wrong

Comment: also do you need to reference lists.txt absolutely? as in: is it in the same folder as where you're calling your python script from?